# Hide payment method based on product meta in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, payment-gateway

We are using this [WooCommerce Custom Fields](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-custom-fields-product-addons/11332742) commercial plugin on our Woocommerce e-shop for individual customization of our products and I am trying to find a way how to hide payment method if key 'wccf' is in product meta.

I am trying to upgrade a code below, I want to replace shipping country checking, but I don't know how to get and check 'wccf' key.

```
function payment_gateway_disable_country( $available_gateways ){
    global $woocommerce;

    if (isset($available_gateways['cod']) && $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country() <> 'IT'){
        unset($available_gateways['cod']);
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_country');
```

Does anybody can you help me?

Comment: item meta =  product meta am  i getting you right?

Comment: I meant [this](https://ctrlv.cz/jGxr)(it is from plugin's documentation)

Comment: Kindly, but this plugin is a real nightmare (with Woocommerce lot of people had unsolved issues with it, here in StackOverFlow)… Instead you should better use [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) free and very well documented plugin or the best way is to make your own custom fields with custom code. **Answerers can't guess how to get the data with your actual plugin…**

Comment: Thank you for a tip, [LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec)! We can try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your support and help! Finally, plugin developer send me a code which solved my problem.

```
$cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
$wccf_is_set = false;

foreach ($cart as $cart_item) {

if (isset($cart_item['wccf'])) {

    // mark that there's data set
    $wccf_is_set = true;
    }
}

if ($wccf_is_set === true) {
// do what you need if the data is set

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code. Put the code in functions.php

```
function payment_gateway_disable_country($available_gateways){
    global $woocommerce;
    if (isset($available_gateways['cod']) && $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country() <> 'IT'){
        //fetching the cart
        $session_data = WC()->session->get('wccf');
        if(!empty($session_data)){
            unset($available_gateways['cod']);
        }   
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_country');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unforunately, it doesn't solve my problem :( I still can see COD in payment methods although I have add a customisation. 

_Here is advice from plugin developer which I get a moment ago "You will just need to iterate all your cart items, check if there's ['wccf'] key set, and if yes - remove the shipping method."_

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following in your filter should do it, assuming the product has a `wccf` entry in its meta data.

```
function payment_gateway_disable_wccf($available_gateways){

    $cart = WC()->cart;

    if( $cart ){

        foreach($cart->get_cart() as $currItem){

            if( get_post_meta($currItem['product_id'], 'wccf', true) )
                unset($available_gateways['cod']);
        }
    }

    return $available_gateways;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_wccf');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unforunately, I still can see COD in payment methods so this code doesn't work. If i add a customization, it will add something like [this](https://ctrlv.cz/y0dE). I have another idea. Is possible to check if word **Gravírovat** is on the cart page?